# Grouping values in Hash Map in Java Stream using custom Collector object?

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

Java Stream newbie here. At the moment I'm finishing chapter 6 (*Collecting data with streams*) on Collectors from this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617291994).

My object looks like this.

```
    public class Report {

    private String movie;
    private int movieId;
    private int projections;
    private int tickets;
    private double income;
}
```

The idea is to get some kind of general summary report. Basically, a `HashMap<String, Double>`
which will have three key-value pairs.

Key 1:

`projections` - which will represent sum of all projections from each Report.

Key 2:

`tickets` - which will represent sum of all tickets from each  Report.

Key 3:

`income` - which will represent sum of all incomes from each Report.

Now, I actually did assignment by creating custom Collector, called `MapCollector`.

```
    public class MapCollector implements Collector<Report, Map<String, Double>, Map<String, Double>>{

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    @Override
    public Supplier<Map<String, Double>> supplier() {

        return () ->  new HashMap<String, Double>() {{
            put("projections", 0.0);
            put("tickets", 0.0);
            put("income", 0.0);
        }};
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<Map<String, Double>, Report> accumulator() {

        return (map, report) -> 
        {
            map.put("projections", map.get("projections") + report.getProjections());
            map.put("tickets", map.get("tickets") + report.getTickets());
            map.put("income", map.get("income") + report.getIncome());          
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<Map<String, Double>> combiner() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Function<Map<String, Double>, Map<String, Double>> finisher() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Function.identity();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.of(
                IDENTITY_FINISH, CONCURRENT));
    }
}
```

So the result I got, which works, looks like this:

```
HashMap<String, Double> result = (HashMap<String, Double>) reports.stream().collect(new MapCollector());
```

So my question is there any why to do this differently without creating new Collector object? Perhaps, somehow to do it with `groupingBy`, or with `reduce` ? Or any other (better) more readable way?

Comment: Sure. Use an actual class, with properties and methods, instead of a Map. Then use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-: `collect(Stats::new, Stats::addReport, Stats::addStats)`. You can also use reduce if you want an immutable reduction. The principle would be similar.

Comment: Thank you JB Nizet for reply. Did you mean like this?                                 
 `return (HashMap<String, Double>) reports.stream().collect(() ->  new HashMap<String, Double>() {  
  {
      put("projections", 0.0);
      put("tickets", 0.0);
      put("income", 0.0);
  }}, 
  (map, report) -> 
  {
   map.put("projections", map.get("projections") + report.getProjections());
   map.put("tickets", map.get("tickets") + report.getTickets());
   map.put("income", map.get("income") + report.getIncome());   
  }, 
  null);` Damn I dont how to make this more readable.sorry sir

Comment: Basically, I just replace lambdas from MapCollector and set them here, "inline". I don't need combiner. so it is null

Comment: Again, Define a class to hold these three attributes, rather than using a map with string keys. `collect(Stats::new, Stats::addReport, Stats::addStats)`. That's what the code should look like.

Comment: First, **do not report `CONCURRENT` when your collector is not concurrent, i.e uses a `HashMap` which does not support concurrent updates**. Second, *do not use the “curly brace initialization” which creates a subclass capturing the surrounding, creating memory leaks*, e.g. the `MapCollector` instance. Third, instead of `map.put("projections", map.get("projections") + report.getProjections())` you can use `map.merge("projections",report.getProjections(), Double::sum)`, likewise for all other updates. The combiner should be a no brainer, as it looks almost the same as the accumulator.

Comment: @Holger Thank you for good suggestions. I'll try to implement and post in the answer, if that is alright.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need a custom Collector for this purpose. All you need are the `supplier`, `accumulator` and `combiner`.

You can put them in the same class as the stream and invoke it like the following:

```
HashMap<String, Double> result = (HashMap<String, Double>) 
                                 reports.stream()
                                        .collect(
                                          this::supplier,
                                          this::acumulator,
                                          this::combiner);
```

Where the methods would look like the following:

```
private Map<String, Double> supplier() {
    return new HashMap<String, Double>() {{
        put("projections", 0.0);
        put("tickets", 0.0);
        put("income", 0.0);
    }};
}

private void accumulator(Map<String, Double> map, Report report) {
    map.merge("projections", report.getProjections(), Double::sum);
    map.merge("tickets", report.getTickets(), Double::sum);
    map.merge("income", report.getIncome(), Double::sum);
}

private void combiner(Map<String, Double> firstMap, Map<String, Double> secondMap) {
    secondMap.forEach((k, v) -> firstMap.merge(k, v, Double::sum));
}
```

Comment: hi, I did exactly what you proposed and it doesn't compile. I get the following message: The type of supplier() from the type ReportServlet is HashMap<String,Double>, this is incompatible with the descriptor's return type: R

Comment: My class is actully some servlet class named ReportServlet...

Comment: A combiner which just overwrites the first results with the second can be considered broken. Writing a correct one, which sums the three mappings, should not be so hard…

Comment: @Holger Thanks indeed I've missed this crucial point. I corrected it now, it should be OK using `compute`

Comment: That works, but is unnecessarily complicated, compared to `firstMap.merge(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), Double::sum)`. As mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59708926/grouping-values-in-hash-map-in-java-stream-using-custom-collector-object/59709254?noredirect=1#comment105662777_59708926), you can use `merge` for the accumulator too. Since `merge` can handle absent keys correctly, you could change the supplier to return an empty map, instead of using the double curly brace initialization.

Comment: Thanks @Holger it is indeed a more concise way of doing it, great to continuously learn new stuff